# Tkinter - Button to add label

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

So I'm currently working with **Tkinter** and I've came quite far on a program I'm trying to create.
Currently I want to have a button which adds labels in the frame.

**Here's my code:**

```
import tkinter as tk

#Window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x700")
root.title("Account Overview")

#Title_Frame
title_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=100, bg='#b1b7ba')
title_frame.pack(side='top')
title_label = tk.Label(title_frame, text="Account Overview", font='Courier 35 underline')
title_label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2)

#Account_Frame
account_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=700, bg='#9dd7f5')
account_frame.pack(side='right')
add_account_button = tk.Button(account_frame, text="Add Account", font='Courier 15')
add_account_button.place(relx=0.26, rely=0.03)
account = tk.Label(account_frame, text="Account Nr1", font='Helvetica 40')
account.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.125)

root.mainloop()
```

Now, if you try the code, you'll see that in the window that gets opened, there's a **side frame**
which displays a button that says **"Add Account"**. Under it you can see a label where it says ***"Account Nr1"***. What I want to happen is that once you open the program, the **"Account Nr1"** label isn't gonna be there, and it is only gonna show up on that exact spot once you click *"Add Account"*.

Comment: Do you want the widget to not be there, or do you just want it to _appear_ to not be there? You can just set the text to an empty string if you don't want the user to see anything until an account has been chosen. GUIs commonly make all of the data fields visible but leave them blank until there is data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, a quick solution is to create the label off screen then move it when the button is clicked.

```
def showlabel():
   account.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.125)  # move on screen

#Account_Frame
account_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=700, bg='#9dd7f5')
account_frame.pack(side='right')
add_account_button = tk.Button(account_frame, text="Add Account", font='Courier 15', command=showlabel)
add_account_button.place(relx=0.26, rely=0.03)
account = tk.Label(account_frame, text="Account Nr1", font='Helvetica 40')
account.place(relx=10.01, rely=0.125)  # off screen

root.mainloop()
```

If you set up your form with a grid, you can hide the label using the `forget` methods: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-forget_pack-and-forget_grid-method-in-tkinter/

--- Update ---

To create labels dynamically, create a label list and use the button to create new labels and append to the list.

```
lbllst = []
def addlabel():
    account = tk.Label(account_frame, text="Account Nr"+str(len(lbllst)+1), font='Helvetica 40')
    account.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.125*(len(lbllst)+1))
    lbllst.append(account)
   
#Account_Frame
account_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=700, bg='#9dd7f5')
account_frame.pack(side='right')
add_account_button = tk.Button(account_frame, text="Add Account", font='Courier 15', command=addlabel)
add_account_button.place(relx=0.26, rely=0.03)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why `place` it at the beginning? Just leave it there, and place it when the button is clicked only?

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a really smart way to solve it!

Comment: Is there a way you can add a label without the label existing in the first place, cause I want the next account label that you wanna create to go right under the first account label that you've created and so on.

Comment: Thank you man, I can't describe how much you're helping me out here! I'm so grateful for your help. Btw, could you keep an eye here in the chat if I would need help with further stuff about this?